# How to index refined null values?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have table with two indexes:

- latest_channel_snapshots_views_idx (view_count DESC NULLS LAST)
- latest_channel_snapshots_network_views_idx (network_id, view_count DESC NULLS LAST)

What I want is to be able to sort by view_count overall, and within specific network. Postgres uses correct index for both of these cases. However, if i want to find record with most views where network_id is NULL, it uses the first index, and filters out the , thus performing really slow:

```
explain analyze SELECT *
FROM latest_channel_snapshots
WHERE network_id IS NULL
ORDER BY view_count DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 500000;

                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=39599.04..39599.44 rows=5 width=74) (actual time=1926.271..1926.287 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using latest_channel_snapshots_views_idx on latest_channel_snapshots  (cost=0.00..42001.59 rows=530336 width=74) (actual time=0.060..1899.224 rows=500005 loops=1)
         Filter: (network_id IS NULL)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 305022
 Total runtime: 1926.309 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Which index is which -- can you name them please?

Comment: Why are you are using `OFFSET 500000`?

Comment: I strongly suspect the `OFFSET 500000` is causing your slow performance. PG knows that it has to scan through 500005 rows and thus wants to use an index to scan rather than scan the underlying table as that causes less IO.

Comment: So, functionally, why do you need such a large offset?

Comment: I'll be paginating through these records via offset. 500,000 is just to demonstrate what slows it down. In reality, it will be up to few thousands..

Comment: edited to include index names..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. large offset: PG will need to scan through the provided offset number of rows and will prefer an index to do this above a table scan.
2. how to index the data: I think a partial index might help you here. Can you try

   create index xxx_idx on latest_channel_snapshots(view_count DESC NULLS LAST) where network_id is null;

   See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-partial.html for more information on partial indexes. In particular, example 11-2 on unbilled orders seems to apply to your case.

Comment: Thanks! Partial index solves the problem. I thought this wasn't necessary, but I was wrong obviously.